# How to plot a multidimensional array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, colormap

I have a table as follows

`system:index   2017_06_18  2017_06_19  2017_06_20  2017_06_21
2               612.8099664 1174.656713 1282.083251 815.3828357
3               766.4103726 1345.135952 1322.726083 749.998993
4               765.0230453 1411.669136 1350.437586 610.9541838
5               553.5858458 1374.14789  1152.086957 566.7924468
6               466.9780908 1311.903756 1060.494001 559.1982264
7               257.1162602 1270.182385 988.5455285 562.9224932
8               230.6611542 1310.971988 1001.548768 502.3266959`

I want to plot a 2d-colormap  representing system:index as y axis, dates as x axis and values under dates as colors. I tried with the following code but it did not give what I want.

```
  clear
  clc
  filename = 'TurbidityDailyMean.xlsx';
  data = xlsread(filename,'TurbidityDailyMean','A1:E8');

  figure;
  hold on

  for i = 2:5
     y = data(:,1);
     x = data(:,i);
   plot(x,y) 
  end
```

I need to map a colormap as mentioned above. But from what I tried it gives something else. And another fact is that I can't insert system:index and dates row into matlab with relevant data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, that you can't insert indeex and dates into matlab? Can you please explain, what exactly you're trying to visualize:  https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/types-of-matlab-plots.html

Comment: I'm trying to visualize a 2d grid colormap(pcolor). the values under dates should represent colors while they categorized under dates on the x axis with system:index on the y axis. when I try to insert the whole excel table the upper row was not included in the `data` array. So i cannot assign dates to x axis and graph it in the matlab.

Comment: Are we talking about the follwoing kind of plot: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html?

Comment: try to read your excel like [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,'TurbidityDailyMean','A1:E8');

Comment: not a surf plot, but a grid wise colored graph for each grid represent a value under dates, dates on the x axis system:index on the y axis.Thanks for the quick reply bushmill. I will try to read the excel file as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my supervisor Dr.Kavinda,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/troAo.png) the solution I adopted from him was as follows

```
data1 = csvread('TurbidityDailyMean.csv',1,1);
[mm,nn]=size(data1)
xx=ones(mm,nn);
yy=ones(mm,nn);
for j=1:nn
        xx(:,j)=j;
end
for i=1:mm
        yy(i,:)=i;
end
zz=data1;


h1=pcolor(xx,yy,zz);
shading flat 
set(gcf,'color',[1,1,1])
axis([1 5 1 7]);

jet2=jet;
jet2(1,:)=1.0;
colormap(jet2)
caxis([0.0 0.13])

hold on
xlabel('Julian Day');
ylabel('y (?~1 km)');
colorb=colorbar;
set(get(colorb,'ylabel'),'String','Normalized Red Band Reflectance','fontsize',15, 
'color', 'k');
set(get(colorb,'xlabel'),'fontsize',20, 'color', 'k');
grid on
```